# getting objects from ArrayList<object>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 3 classes: one that is abstract named `MyClass1` and two others that extend `MyClass1` named `MyClass2` and `MyClass3`.

I create an `ArrayList` which is `MyClass1` type
ex :

```
ArrayList<MyClass1> myArray=new ArrayList<MyClass1>();
```

Then I create some objects in class `MyClass2` and `MyClass3` and add them in the `ArrayList` that I created previously. The question is how can I use the objects that I added in the `ArrayList` in order to call methods

Comment: Don't name your class Object.

Comment: You have to cast them into your desired class. E.g. Object2 obj2 = (Object2) myArray.get(0); Because ArrayList<Object> always returns Object and not Object2 or Object3

Comment: With the `get` method?

Comment: The Object class is the parent class of all the classes in java by default.So you should not use it.

Comment: To add on what @MuratK. said for the future, try to never name any class the same as any class in the package `java.lang`.

Comment: burrito, did you ever take the [tour]? If not, now would be a good time to do so. Remember: you are supposed to upvote helpful answers and eventually mark the one that solved your issue as *accepted*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: If your Base class (`Object1`) got the Method, you can call it on every Child Class (`Object2` / `Obejct3`)

Option 2: If you want to call a method on your Child Class which is not defined in your base class, you need to cast your Object to the Specific class in order to call the method.

Example:

```
for (Object1 myObject1 : myArray){
  if (myObject1 instanceof Object2){
    Object2 myObject2 = (Object2)myObject1;
    myObject2.myMethod();
  }
}
```

And yes, dont name your class `Object` since this name is already used by Java as "Base/Root Object".

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, don't name your classes Object.

You will have to cast the objects in order to call methods declared in subclasses:

```
abstract class FirstClass {

    public void firstMethod() {

    }
}

class SecondClass extends FirstClass {

    public void secondMethod() {

    }
}

class ThirdClass extends FirstClass {

    public void thirdMethod() {

    }
}

....

public void run() {
    ArrayList<FirstClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new SecondClass());
    list.add(new ThirdClass());

    for (FirstClass obj : list) {
        obj.firstMethod(); //No cast needed

        if (obj instanceof SecondClass) {
            SecondClass objOfSecond = (SecondClass) obj;
            objOfSecond();
        }

        if (obj instanceof ThirdClass) {
            ThirdClass objOfThird = (ThirdClass) obj;
            objOfThird();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was a bit difficult to understand, given the use of Object as a keyword in Java, an word with specific meaning when talking about object-oriented languages, and now a specific class, so I'll rename the class we're talking about to `SomeObject`.

When your ArrayList of `SomeObject` objects is declared, it will look like this:

```
List<SomeObject> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

You then add instances of SomeObject:

```
myArray.add(new SomeObject());
```

And then you can access objects by index, and call methods directly on that object. Here, I call the `someMethod` method of the `SomeObject` class.

```
int i = 0; //used as index
myArray.get(i).someMethod();
```

Keep in mind that if `SomeObject`has subclasses (such as `SomeOtherObject`), you are definitely allowed to add instances of `SomeOtherObject` to your `SomeObject` ArrayList. But, you will run into issues if you have added multiple subclasses to the ArrayList, and then try to call a method that is unique to a subclass.

Hope this helps!